# definite integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{r^3}{(r^2+d^2)^3} dr$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{r^3}{(r^2+d^2)^3} dr$$

I am completely stumped how to solve this integral for a physics problem. I thought about trying to write it in terms of partial fractions with denominators that are multiples of $(r-d)$ and $(r+d)$ but I got lost in the algebra.

Are there any suitable substitutions that might help solve this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align} \\ & \int_0^\infty\frac{r^3}{(r^2+d^2)^3} dr \\ &
=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_0^\infty\frac{r^2}{(r^2+d^2)^3}\cdot (2rdr) \end{align}$$

Now we take $z=r^2+d^2$ and hence $dz=2rdr$.

Also when $r=o$, $z=d^2$ and when $r\to \infty$, $z\to \infty$.

Therefore we have that

$$\begin{align} \\ & = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{d^2}^\infty \frac{z-d^2}{z^3}dz \\ & = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{d^2}^\infty\frac{z-d^2}{z^3}dz \\ &
= \frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{d^2}^\infty \frac{1}{z^2}dz - \frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{d^2}^\infty \frac{d^2}{z^3}dz \\ & 
= \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{d^2} - \frac{d^2}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2d^4}dz \\ &
= \frac{1}{2d^2} - \frac{1}{4d^2} \\ &
= \frac{1}{4d^2} \end{align}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: @goods You can have a look at this simple substitution.

Comment: I think your final result should be divided by $2$, i.e. the final result is $1/(4d^2)$ (the mistake is that $1/2-1/4\neq 1/2$ but $1/4$). Also, there is a $dz$ on the last rows that probably should not be there.

Comment: Nice substitution. (+1)

Comment: @mickep Thanks for helping. Typo corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Write it as:

$$r^2 \times  \frac{r}{(r^2 + d^2)^3}$$

Then integrate by parts.